# Can't read NSData for some photos

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to get list of thumbnails of all my camera roll photos, but for some photos I can't read NSData.

```
PHFetchResult *allPhotosResult = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithMediaType:PHAssetMediaTypeImage options:nil];

for(PHAsset *asset in allPhotosResult) {
    [[PHImageManager defaultManager]
        requestImageForAsset:asset
    targetSize:CGSizeMake(80, 80)
    contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFill
    options:nil
    resultHandler:^(UIImage *result, NSDictionary *info) {
        NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(result); // nil for some photos
        NSString *base = [data base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithLineFeed];
    }];
}
```

Comment: By default, fetch results do not include photos synced to the device through iTunes or stored in iCloud Shared Albums. To change this behavior, use the includeAssetSourceTypes property in the options parameter. May be thats missing?

Comment: No, I just added this option and then PHFetchResult contains 0 photos :/